# Trying to add text in Wordpress page - Main Index Template (index.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using oria theme for my blog. It has grid layout on home page. I would like to add a post on homepage under the grid and pagination. I tried to copy paste the Single post code, but didn't see any changes in the home page. Please guide me to add a post/article on home page, as I am not a technical person.

Index.php code

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is not just a php website. index.php is not necessarily displaying your homepage. You will need to go to your Wordpress Admin console > Settings > Reading and see what is set for "your homepage displays". You can then reference the [Wordpress Template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to see what file is actually being displayed on your homepage.

Then, when you find the right spot in the right file, if you want to display a particular post you can't just copy/paste the loop from single.php as the things necessary for that to work do not happen on the homepage. You will need to use the function get_posts() with some parameters to return the post you want. Then you can use the functions from single.php on the returned post object to display it.

I know I threw a lot at you in this post, so please leave comments if you get hung up on any of these steps.

Comment: Done. It was home.php where the changes were needed. Thanks for your help Max.